# Может ли быть присвоен знак «Страж» если для проверок недостаточно репутации?

Tags: поддержка, правки, знаки, репутация

Заглянул в профиль одного из пользователей подсайта и, с удивлением, увидел знак ["Страж"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/custodian?userid=181256). Сам по себе знак как знак, но у пользователя репутация — 1 (причём, учитывая минусы за его вопрос, у него могла бы быть и отрицательная репутация, если бы это предусматривал движок).

Теперь, собственно, суть вопроса. Как пользователь мог получить доступ к очереди "Предлагаемые правки", в которую пускают только с репутацией больше `1000`?

Comment: У меня вчера была [такая же ситуация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/custodian?userid=282308). Я тоже сначала удивился, но потом порыскал по Мета, нашел ответы и успокоился )))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Упомянутый вами пользователь принял предложенную другим пользователем правку к своему вопросу.

Как автор вопроса, согласитесь, он волен принимать и отклонять правки, вносимые другими участниками в его вопрос.

Comment: Я совершенно ничего не имею против. Просто не знал что бывает так. Подумал что по каким-то причинам движок сайта допустил пользователя к очереди или знак был присвоен в результате сбоя. Спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Может этот вопрос стОит удалить?

Comment: @tutankhamun, может лучше тег ему поменять. Мне, например, интересно узнать, что можно таким образом знаки получать :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Поменял теги. Я вот тоже не догадался как этот знак был получен, но я вопросы задавал только на "мете" - у меня не было опыта работы с вопросами

Comment: @Qwertiy: при должном старании можно так и золотой знак получить )